# can we make a convolution network that use more than one image to make a prediction

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I cropped the following image from a tutorial.

[image]

this diagram shows a rough structure of a standard neural network. takes one image as input and make a prediction.

what I am thinking about is some kind of parallel structure. think about something like the following image.
[image]

not exactly as in the above image. But you can see I am trying to use two images to make one prediction. this image is for you to get an idea about what I am trying to ask.

is it possible to use more than one (two, three ..) images like this or any other way in order to make one prediction. now, this is not to be used in actual photo classification. But I think such a technique can be used in a file like audio classification where a graphical representation of data is used with image classification techniques.

any advice, guidance or opinion on this?

if we consider implementing exactly what is in the diagram, if I use a high-level API like Keras (Keras.model.sequential) all we can do is keep adding a layer one after the other.

so what kind of technology can I use to implement the parallel structure

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use more than one image as input. See for example the [Siamese Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network) which takes as input 2 images and passes them through a shared network architecture.

If instead you want to have an arbitrary and variable number of images as input you can use an architecture based on Recurrent Neural Networks like [Convolutional LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/), which essentially applies a CNN to every image of the input sequence using an LSTM recurrent network.